# Recursion and list comprehension?

Tags: python, string, list, recursion, list-comprehension

is "lst[1:-1]" any different from "lst[1:]" ? in this situation:

```
def is_pal(string):
    if len(string) < 2:
        return True
    elif string[0] != string[-1]:
        return False
    else:
        return is_pal(string[1:-1])
```

The code is Checking whether string is palindrome.

Comment: `string[1:-1]` returns the string except for the first and last characters while `string[1:]` returns the string except for the first character

Answer (score 1):

-1 is exclusive, meaning [1:-1] will return the whole string except for the first (0) and the last characters.

BTW you can just reverse the text and check it that way:

```
def is_pal(string):
    return string[::-1] == string
```

Answer (score 1):

consider a string,

`s = "abcdef"`

`s[1:] = "bcdef"`

`s[1:-1] = "bcde"`

To check whether the given string is palindrome or not,
just compare the given string `s` with string `s[::-1]`.